# xUnit with Jenkins: how to display colors in the Build Console Output?

Tags: jenkins, styles, casperjs, xunit

I successfully setup CasperJS test suite exporting to an xUnit XML file that way:

```
$ casperjs test googletesting.js --xunit=log.xml
```

I managed to automate these tests through Jenkins thanks to the [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin).

I even managed to setup emails notifications when a build fails thanks to [Mail Watcher Plugin][3] which is great !

The only problem is the format of the output, it's a bit messy.
In the build console output and in my email notifications I see the following:

```
[37;46;1mTest file: tests.js[0m
[33m# TEST XXX[0m
[32;1mPASS[0m #aaa found
[32;1mPASS[0m #bbb found
[32;1mPASS[0m ccc found
[32;1mPASS[0m ddd found
```

In the [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mail+Watcher+Plugin) page, it says:

> For each xUnit tool, an embedded style sheet is used. However, the plugin also enables you to use a custom style sheet for your own tool such as WebUI

Is there a way to display the build output so that it's styled properly with beautiful colors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hurray !

Actually, describing my problem made me investigate and find a solution !

I just needed to install the [AnsiColor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) and check the **Color ANSI Console Output** box from the **Build Environment** !

More info here: http://code.dblock.org/the-jenkins-ansicolor-plugin-youve-all-been-waiting-for

It now displays beautiful colors in my Console Output.

Still shitty in my email notifications but who cares ?...

Hope it can help !