# How can I change FAIL output details at casperjs test?

Tags: casperjs

I would like to make some changes at the message of output FAIL test. 
For example:

- Hide **type** and **file** parameters;
- Rename **subject** and **expected** parameters;

I tried to use `casper.test.on('fail', function (failure) { casper.test.comment("mylabel: " + failure.values.subject);})` to output my message and it worked, but the default parameters were not hidden.

Some idea?
 [image]

Comment: Not sure but it seems you can get a clue here (rewrite error msg): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23468730/5885018

Comment: I tried it but doesn't worked as expected.